# Identifying multiple spam messages / appropriate course of action?

Tags: discussion, spam

https://stackoverflow.com/users/945923/ryan-moore

This account was created six days ago and has 10 answers (out of 15 total) that all start with the same paragraph. Maybe a bit suspicious on its own, but they're all related questions, so maybe just trying to be helpful and spread the same info across answers.

But then comes the part where every one of them features links to the same product. And he seems to also be in the SEO consulting business as well? Just seems a little inappropriate.

I'm hesitant to go through and mark each of the 10 questions as spam as they should be seen/reviewed as a whole - not individually.

What does anyone else think? Do something? Leave it alone?

Comment: I predict this will not end well for the page on the other side of that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is **flag one of the suspect posts for moderator attention**, explaining in the comment that you noticed a pattern with this user and what it is. We'll take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Those answers definitely look suspect to me. For example, [I really don't think that this "answer" addresses the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749422/dotnetnuke-module-development-roadblocks-where-is-my-module/7425811#7425811). If you break it down, it essentially says "the solution is to buy XMod Pro." Also note that if this user can post the same answer to more than one question, those questions should have been closed as duplicates in the first place. I'm marking the answer above as spam.

I also find it suspicious that every single answer was posted on September 15th.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do both. On a number of occasions recently I have flagged one of a user's posts for moderator attention with the explanation about the group of posts, *and* flagged all of the relevant posts as spam. I was doing it that way because I figured it was quicker for moderators to go through the spam queue to kill the relevant posts, rather than make them go to the user's profile and work out which of the posts were dubious.

I don't know if it is intended behaviour to be able to flag a post twice, once for spam and once for moderator attention, but it works for me.